# SingleLaunchActivityTestCase not working when two different classes extend it

Tags: android, instrumentation

This is the scenario:

I am having two classes extended from SingleLaunchActivityTestCase.

```
public class ABCTest extends SingleLaunchActivityTestCase<ABCActivity>
```

and

```
public class XYZTest extends SingleLaunchActivityTestCase<XYZActivity>
```

These are their respective constructors and setUp methods:

```
public ABCTest() {
    super("com.android", ABCActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = this.getActivity();
}
```

and

```
public ABCTest() {
    super("com.android", XYZActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = this.getActivity();
}
```

Now on running using te android testRunner the testcases in the ABCTest work but for the XYZTest i get the following exception:

```
java.lang. java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.ABCActivity
at com.instrument.XYZTest.setUp(XYZTest.java:45)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

But on running these tests , i.e the ABC Tests and the XYZ tests separately it works fine.

The problem seems to be with the line `this.getActivity()` in the `setUp()` method.
Aftes ABC tests are through the `setUp()` of XYZ tests returns `com.android.ABCActivity` for `this.getActivity()` instead of `com.android.XYZActivity`

Seems strange........can anyone please help out??????

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having problems with getting the Activity from the previous test as the current Activity class.

I think it is a problem with the SingleLaunchActivityTestCase. If you are using this in your tests, I think your test suite should only be run with one single Activity. If you are testing multiple activities, I recommend using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 instead.

You could try to finish the Activity in your teardown methods and set this.activity to null also if you wish to continue using SingleLaunchActivityTestCase and see if that helps:

```
public void tearDown() {
  super.tearDown();
  this.getActivity().finish();
}
```